# Postman test Chaining post request result to get request uri param

Tags: api, postman-collection-runner, postman-testcase

I have to write postman test for below requests.

1. Post {{url}}/{{version}}/Customers will return customer object which contains customerId
2. Get {{url}}/{{version}}/Customers/{{customerId}}

So I need to run both request according to above sequence

So when the Customer is created then assign {{customerId}} so Get request will return new customer id.

Is this possible to chain the result (customerId) post request to get request

Comment: What's the structure of the response object? Adding `pm.globals.set('customerId', pm.response.json().path.to.id)` to the Tests tab of the POST request would store the value. Then the GET request would resolve the `{{customerId}}` placeholder value. This is using a global variable but you could just use a different scope.

Comment: I already found the solution. any way thanks @DannyDainton